# Unable to output to text file in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell-4.0

I have been trying to do out-file to a .text file but have been unsuccessful. All I get is an empty text file. I am also working with an XML file, if that makes a difference.

## Get number of files modified

```
$NumFiles = $IndivdualXML | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

$Out = Write-Host "Total number of files modified :" $NumFiles
```

## Save to text file

```
$Out | Out-File -FilePath C:\TEMP\QC\ChangeLog.text -Append
```

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6#outputs) `Write-Host` Cmdlet does not return any object.

> Write-Host sends the objects to the host. It does not return any objects. However, the host might display the objects that Write-Host sends to it.

Based on that `$Out` does not contain the string you expect. This can be fixed by changing the code as follows.

```
$NumFiles = $IndivdualXML | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count;
$Out = "Total number of files modified : {0}" -f $NumFiles;
$Out | Out-File -FilePath C:\Logs\ChangeLog.txt
```